# Error while compiling .asm file on visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, assembly, x86-64

So I have this `.asm` file inside my visual studio kernelmode driver:

```
.code 
DispatchHook proc
    add rsp, 8h
    mov rax, 0DEADBEEFCAFEBEEFh
    jmp rax
DispatchHook endp

end
```

However when I try to build my solution I get this error `The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.25.28610\bin\HostX86\arm\armasm.exe" -coff_thumb2_only -o ARM\Release\DispatchHook.obj ARM\Release\DispatchHook.i" exited with code 1`, it seems that there is an error with the assembly code, however I don't know what.

Comment: Looks like the project is setup for ARM, not X64 (64 bit mode X86). Check the settings so that the build is in X64 mode, and is done using ML64.EXE (64 bit version of MASM) (use a custom build step if needed).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the release version from `ARM` to `x64`;